# Centering with 3 authors in Latex?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, ieeeconf

My paper having 3 different authors with a common affiliation. I am trying to center the third author position using `centering` command but it's not working. Its IEEE conference latex version.I used below script:

```
    \begin{document}

\title{Paper Title*\\
{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and
should not be used}
\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{\textsuperscript{}Ali}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{School of Engineering and Information Technology } \\
\textit{The University of New South Wales (UNSW) }\\
 Australia \\
}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{\textsuperscript{}Abbass}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{School of Engineering and Information Technology} \\
\textit{The University of New South Wales (UNSW) }\\
 Australia \\
}
\and
\centering
\IEEEauthorblockN{\textsuperscript{} sayed}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{School of Engineering and Information Technology} \\
\textit{The University of New South Wales }\\
 Australia \\
}

}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try manually adding some horizontal space. Not the best solution, I know, but still worth a try while waiting a proper answer.

Comment: @EdoardoSerra.I was wondering,what is the function of \centering command?

Comment: @CaseMsee.The function of \centering is to add or remove just the right amount of horizontal space so that, in this case, the block of text results correctly centred in the middle of the page respect to its margins. If it is not working try to manually add some horizontal space using the \hspace{} command instead of the \centering one and inserting in it a value to shift the text. This is not a nice nor a very precise solution, but if you do that accurately enough it could avoid the problem until a better and nicer solution will be posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

**SOURCE: bare_conf.tex from IEEE**

For over three affiliations, or if they all won't fit within the width  of the page, use this alternative format:

```
\begin{document}

\title{Paper Title*\\
{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and
should not be used}
\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Ali\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Abbass\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
sayed\IEEEauthorrefmark{3},
}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\textit{School of Engineering and Information Technology } \\
\textit{The University of New South Wales (UNSW) }\\
 Australia \\}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}\textit{School of Engineering and Information Technology} \\
\textit{The University of New South Wales (UNSW) }\\
 Australia \\
}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}\textit{School of Engineering and Information Technology} \\
\textit{The University of New South Wales }\\
 Australia \\
}
}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Saravanan.But i need to use the same format as i mentioned in question.No command in Latex to align the third author at center?